# Redirect everything to https.www and keep url path

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, http-redirect

Using the default Laravel htaccess I have added a redirect, but it is not doing what I need it to do.

I need everything be redirect to https://www and keep the requested path.

Eg. domain.com/mypath > https://www. domain.com/mypath

Eg. www.domain.com/mypath > https://www. domain.com/mypath

Eg. (all possible variations).domain/my path > https://www. domain.com/mypath

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Added by ME
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.nz/$1 [R,L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index [NC]    
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L,NE]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Change the order, and do this rewrite first, before all the other stuff ...

Comment: Cbroe - Thank you, it worked.